# Find the utility of each agent whenever the social welfare is maximized

Tags: utility, self-study, optimization

Question:

Suppose that the utility possibilities curve of 2 people economy is given by the equation $u_1^2 + Au_2^2=20$ where $A\in R_+$ and the social welfare function of the economy is $W(u_1,u_2)=u_1+u_2$. Find the utility of each agent whenever the social welfare is maximized.

---

In fact, I cannot understand from the question, and I cannot imagine how to solve the question.

but, I use Lagrangian method as follows:

$$max \{u_1+u_2 \}$$

subject to $$u_1^2 + Au_2^2=20 $$

And I found that

$$(u_1^*, u_2^*) = (\sqrt{\frac{20A}{A+1}}, \sqrt{\frac{20}{A(A+1)}})$$

And there are no boundary solutions.

Is this solution approach true? Or Do I have any mistake or misunderstanding?

Please share your ideas and hints with me. I will appreciate you for that. Thank you.